# Ruby on Rails, Send a copy of all outgoing emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, mandrill, amazon-ses

I would like to save a copy of every email sent from RoR.
Is there a way ask ActionMailer to send a copy of every email send to a specific address (possibly ass bcc)

> Background: *I have been doing this using Mandrillapp automatically using "send a copy of every email to this address" from their settings page. I am
>   now moving from Mandrill to Amazon SES and would like to continue
>   using a similar functionality.*

Comment: so you want to cc'd to specific people?

Comment: Yes, I am thinking about cc'ing specific people, but without modifying the mail calls (I have many of them), is there a way to specify a cc by default for every mail call?

Comment: not really related: i will suggest to use mailgun. from there you can do whatever you want with your mails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set `bcc` on the mail method:  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

You could also simply send a copy of the same email contents with another `mail()` call.

Comment: I used the ::default class method to set the default bcc right after the UserMailer class declaration:
 default bcc: 'email_logger@test.lindsaar.net'
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should try this -

```
mail(to: "a@mail.com", subject: "Test",
     bcc: "b@mail.com",
     cc: "c@mail.com")
```

Comment: not really related: i will suggest to use mailgun. from there you can do whatever you want with your mails.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an observer:

```rb
class EmailDeliveryObserver
  def self.delivered_email(message)
    EmailDelivery.log(message)
  end
end
```

```rb
Rails.application.configure do
  config.action_mailer.observers = %w[EmailDeliveryObserver]
end
```

From: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#observing-emails